pdal piepline to load pgpointcloud data in memory
Here pdal's pgpointcloud reading and writing is documented.
We define pipeline with read and write steps. Write step puts data in a file on disk.
Is it possible to instead put data in memory so that it can be used in a software program for manipulation?

Would Python be an option for you? You could read the pointcloud using the Python API and read the data with NumPy.
